# WCF WsHttpBinding on linux

Tags: linux, wcf, soap

I need to consume WCF service on linux. The service uses wsHttpBinding with message security, secure conversation and ws trust (tlsnego). I tried to use gSoap, python (zeep) and .NET Core but no success. Finaly I will need a solution in C++ but for now I just need to communicate (authenticate) with service from linux. The problem is that I can't find any tools that supports configuration like this. Can you suggest any solution?

Comment: I don’t know much about gsoap but I found a similar question on msdn, hope it can help you: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ba804ede-8b78-404f-9498-738a97f00364/wcf-service-with-wshttpbinding-and-gsoap-client?forum=wcf

Comment: Another solution is to use basichttpbinding. You can create a .net core application in linux to call WCF services, because core does not support wshttpbinding.